# RouterOutlet malfunction with Navbar

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm not entirely sure what is going on here. I have a navbar like so:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div>
  <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Haipe</a>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Home</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/events']">Events</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/add-event']">Add Event</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a (click)="logout()" >Logout</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
</nav>
```

The Dashboard component has the navBar and the routerOutlet. However, when I click the link it doesn't place the contents of the component under the navBar, which should be the default behavior of the router element. It is sending me to a whole different page.

These are the routes that I have defined. Below is the `app.Module.ts` file which has all of my routes:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { LoginFormComponent } from './components/login-form/login-form.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import {RouterModule,Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { Route } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';

//Firebase configuration
import {AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import {AngularFireAuthModule} from 'angularfire2/auth';

//Forms
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
//All Components
import { EventsComponent } from './components/events/events.component';
import { EventDetailsComponent } from './components/event-details/event-details.component';
import { AddEventComponent } from './components/add-event/add-event.component';
import { EditEventComponent } from './components/edit-event/edit-event.component';
import { DeleteEventComponent } from './components/delete-event/delete-event.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { Component } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/directives';

const appRoutes:Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginFormComponent
  },{
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },{
    path: 'events',
    component: EventsComponent
  },{
    path: 'add-event',
    component: AddEventComponent
  },{
    path: 'edit-event/:id',
    component: EditEventComponent
  },{
    path: 'delete-event/:id',
    component: DeleteEventComponent
  },{
    path: 'event-details',
    component: EventDetailsComponent
  }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    LoginFormComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    EventsComponent,
    EventDetailsComponent,
    AddEventComponent,
    EditEventComponent,
    DeleteEventComponent,
    NavbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),AngularFirestoreModule,AngularFireAuthModule,
    BrowserModule,FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Forgot to include DashBoard component

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: so nobody has a solution?

Comment: With a quick look at the code, there is nothing obvious I see. Are there any errors in the console? And what do you mean by "sending to a whole other page"? Do you have other router outlets in the application?

Comment: yes I have one other router outlet in the application @DeborahK

Comment: Is that the one it is routing to?

Comment: well I'm not entirely sure that router outlet is responsible for a login component which redirects to the dashboard which contains the navbar. The router outlet shown there is display the contents of the component below the navbar in the dashboard

Comment: @DeborahK is it possible to move this to chat?

Comment: I read somewhere that when you have multiple outlets you should name them is that true? @DeborahK

Comment: I don't use the chat feature here. And to answer your question, it depends on how you lay them out. If you don't have them laid out as child outlets, then you have to name all but the "main" one. Otherwise the router does not know which router outlet you mean to use at any particular time.

Comment: even when i named them I saw no change @DeborahK could you show me an example

Comment: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-routing

Comment: OR https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing (which includes aux routes and child routes).